# Php. Как сохранить в нужную директорию?

Tags: php

Название директории лежит в TXT-файле (`directory.txt`)
Как в данном случае сохранить файл в нужную директорию?

```html
$f = fopen($key.".html", "a");
fwrite($f, $html);
fclose($f);
```

**P.S. Мало знаком с PHP, пытаюсь сделать сайт, но без посторонней помощи никак**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как то так, но лучше подробнее напишите вопрос

```
 $dirs = file_get_contents('dir.txt');
    $file_paths = explode(';',$dirs);
    foreach($file_paths as $key=>$value){
    file_put_contents($value,$content);
    }
```

Comment: $f = fopen($dirs. '/' . $key . '.html', "a");

Вот так сделал, спасибо за идею